# rerendering events in fullCalendar after Ajax database update

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

I am trying to have fullCalendar reflect changes made to a database via AJAX. The problem is that it won't update the calendar on screen after a successful AJAX call.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "eventEditXHR.php",
    data: {
       //the data
    },
    success: function(text) {
      $("#calendar").fullCalendar("refetchEvents");
    }....
```

I'm I using the wrong method? What would be the best way to accomplish this without having to reload the whole page? Thanks for any input!

Comment: Did you assign var calendar = $("#calendar").Fullcalender... ? Try with calendar.fullcalendar("refetchEvents");

Comment: Yes, but neither of those work.

Comment: Try $("#calendar").fullCalendar("Refresh");

Comment: That function has been removed. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

There are several ways. Some less elegant.

#### 1. If you are using FullCalendar to grab json events:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({ events: "json-events.php",    });
```

Just do:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );
```

#### If you want outside method to fetch events you could do. Not elegant but will work

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'removeEventSource', source )
$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', source )
```

Comment: the `removeEventSource` might not works well in this case as the 1st data fetch from ajax  might disappear when you are in 2nd data fetch from ajax. It may difficult to remove events in 1st data fetch

Comment: Not works for me. $(document).ready(function() {
 $("#overviewDatePicker").datepicker(
 {
  onSelect: function(event){
 var start=$("#overviewDatePicker").val();
 var end="2016-10-21";
 $.ajax({
  url:"fullcalendar/demos/php/get-events.php?mode=customdate&start="+start+"&end="+end,
  type:"GET",
  success:function(result){
   $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
   $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', result); 
   $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents' );   
  }
      });
           },
  });
});

Comment: $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'removeEventSource', source ) does not work for me but $ ('#calendar').fullCalendar ('removeEvents'); does.

Comment: Does anyone knows how to do the same in latest version of fullcalendar v5?

Answer (score 52):

You can render events in 3 steps..

1) remove all events

```
.fullCalendar( 'removeEvents');
```

2) add event sourse

```
.fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', events);
```

3) render events

```
.fullCalendar( 'rerenderEvents' );
```

Like...

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "eventEditXHR.php",
    data: {       //the data    },
    success: function(events)
      {
              $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
              $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', events);         
              $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents' );
       }.
     });
```

Comment: i tried it but not works for me. see my code. $(document).ready(function() {
 $("#overviewDatePicker").datepicker(
 {
  onSelect: function(event){
 var start=$("#overviewDatePicker").val();
 var end="2016-09-10";
 $.ajax({
  url:"fullcalendar/demos/php/get-events.php?mode=customdate&start="+start+"&end="+end,
  type:"GET",
  success:function(result){
   console.log(result);
   $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
   $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', result); 
   $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents' );   
  }
      });
           },
  });
});

Comment: @anupama can you explain this for a newbie ? im the same problem

Comment: i am also having the same problem. but i am loading events from google calendar.
is any suggestion .?

Answer (score 4):

For FullCalendar v3.8.0 the following will work:

```
var events = [
    {title: 'Business Lunch', start: '2017-12-03T13:00:00'},
    {title: 'Meeting', start: '2017-12-13T11:00:00'},
    {title: 'Conference', start: '2017-12-18', end: '2017-12-20'},
];

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultDate: '2017-12-12',
    events: function (start, end, tz, callback) {
        callback(events);
    }
});

events.push({title: 'Party', start: '2017-12-29T20:00:00'});
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
```

[jsbin](https://jsbin.com/tocetizupo/edit?html,output)

Answer (score 3):

This is what works in ASP.NET CORE, MVC 6 :

```
 success: function(events)
 {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
 }
```

while this was working in ASP.NET MVC 5:

```
 success: function(events)
 {
       $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

What works for me:

```
success: function(text) {
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $("#calendar").fullCalendar("rerenderEvents");
                },50);
            }
```

If I do it directly without timeout it does not work, probable due to the $element.fullCalendar variable not yet set completely?

Answer (score 1):

**One line does the work:**

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEventSources', 'eventEditXHR.php')
```

Late reply, but this should be the most efficient way since 2.8.0

Answer (score 0):

```
 eventDrop: function (event, delta, revertFunc) {
            var id = event.id;
            var start = event.start.format();

            $.ajax({
                url: getURLRoot() + 'Diary/UpdateEventTimestamp',
                type: "POST",
                data: { id: id, start: start },
                success: function () {
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you call the refetchevents in the ajax success function it will not work as it is async i believe. But what you can do is call the refetchevents in the ajax complete function.

```
          $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/TaxCalendar/CreateEvent",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ jdata: json }),
                    //data: jdata,
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (events) {


                    }, complete: function () {
                        //Call Refetch function here.
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                    }
                });
```