# fullcalendar: unable to live refresh the calendar after adding an event via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

**Problem**

I am struggling to get my newly added event to show after I have added it via an AJAX request... I am following the suggestions here in this answer: [rerendering events in fullCalendar after Ajax database update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21204305/rerendering-events-in-fullcalendar-after-ajax-database-update) but it is not working as expected. No refreshes are taking place.

I still have to manually refresh the page to see my newly created event.

**My Code**

```
(function(){

    var calendar = {

        init: function(){
            this.getEvents();
        },
        /**
         * 
         */
        getEvents: function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo base_url('teach/schedule/showAllEvents'); ?>',
                type: 'post',
                async: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(events){
                    calendar.initCalendar(events);
                },
            });

        },
        /**
         *
         */
        initCalendar: function(events){
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
                editable: true,
                events: events,
                eventColor: '#7cd97c',
                slotDuration: '00:15:00',
                slotEventOverlap: false,
                eventDurationEditable: false,
                eventOverlap: false,
                allDaySlot: false,
                /**
                 * add events here
                 */
                dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
                    $('#myModal').modal('show');
                    $('#myModal').find('.modal-title').text('Schedule a new lesson');
                    $('#modalContent').html(Mustache.render($('#scheduleNewLessonTemplate').html()));
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '<?php echo base_url('teach/students/showAllStudents'); ?>',
                        type: 'post',
                        async: false,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function(data){
                            var html = '';
                            var i;
                            for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                                html += '<option value="' + data[i].student_id + '">' +
                                            '<td>' + data[i].first_name + ' ' + data[i].last_name  + ' (' + data[i].email + ')</td>' +
                                        '</option>'
                            }
                            $('#listOfStudents').html(html);
                        }
                    });
                    $('#starts').val(date.format());
                    $('#submitForm').on('click', function(){
                        data = $('#theForm').serialize();
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'ajax',
                            method: 'post',
                            url: '<?php echo base_url('teach/schedule/addEvent'); ?>',
                            data: data,
                            async: false,
                            dataType: 'json',
                            success: function(response){
                                calendar.getEvents();
                                $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' ); // I still have to refresh the page to see changes!

                            },
                        });
                    });
                },
            })
        }
    };

    calendar.init();

})();
```

**Question**

How do I get my events to update after the addEvent ajax call?

Comment: try putting $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' ); in getEvents after that gets a success. Otherwise it will be called before the new event is retrieved

Comment: Absolutely spot on... and for the record I had to add these two calls: $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'removeEvents'); $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', events);